# An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Facing some trouble in solving this problem - 'An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')'

I have tried to check the typeof string using the if condition. And if the condition satisfies, then I'm applying the split method. But that didn't work.

setInterval function is where I have tried to solve the problem by applying if condition and logging the result in the console.

The split method appears in several files. Unable to find out which file the error is pointing out to. Below are some of the files where the method occurs.

Will be grateful for any help!

Thanks.

```
    setInterval(function () {
      const random = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);

      const checkvalues = updatingChart.text();

      if(typeof checkvalues === 'string') {
      let values = checkvalues.split(',');
      console.log(values);

      values.shift();
      // values.push(random);

      updatingChart
        .text(values.join(','))
        .change();
      }
    }, 1000);
...
}
```

```
 TopMarket() {
    this.TopMarketGraph = {
      title: {
        left: 'center',
        top: 'top'
      },
      tooltip: {
        trigger: 'item',
        formatter: function (params) {
          let value = (params.value + '').split('.');
          return params.seriesName + '<br/>' + params.name + ' : ' + value;
        }
      }, 
....
}
```

```
 convertMonthly(data) {
    if (data.length > 0) {
      if (data[0].length == 7) {
        let monthInRow = [];
        data.forEach((element) => {
          var dates = element.split('-')[1];
          monthInRow.push(this.mapMonth[dates]);
        });
        return monthInRow;
      }
      else {
        return data;
      }
    }
  }

sendLanguages() {
    let params = {};
    let userinfo = this.localStorageService.fetchStoredUserClient();
    this.params['client_id'] = userinfo['client_id'];
    if (this.optionsModel) {
      if (this.optionsModel.length > 0) {
        this.emptyDropdownError = false;
        if (this.MonthlySelected) {
          if (this.dateSelected['to_date'].split("-")[2] = this.dateSelected['from_date'].split("-")[2] == 6) {
            params = this.dateSelected;
          } else {
            params['from_date'] = this.dateSelected['to_date'].substring(0, this.params['from_date'].lastIndexOf("-"));
            params['to_date'] = this.dateSelected['to_date'].substring(0, this.params['to_date'].lastIndexOf("-"));
          }
        } else {
          params = this.dateSelected;
        }
```

Comment: Are you not seeing the file name and line number in your chrome's devtools?

Comment: No, I'm getting the error in vscode terminal every time I serve the Angular application using cmd 'ng serve'.

Comment: Can you attach any screenshot of error?

Comment: In the console, I see "The variable does not store a string"  followed by "Cannot read properties of undefined" which happens on the second split where there is no type check. It would seem that updatingChart.text() is returning null.

Comment: @FahadSubzwari Here's a link for screenshot of the error - https://www.kapwing.com/videos/63b594ace0f9890061fedeed

Comment: @Donald did you debug or print on console the value of `checkvalues ` inside of function `setInterval` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried logging the value of checkvalues inside setInterval function